# Wireless doorbell transmitters and receivers

Tags: bluetooth, transmitter, receiver

Im a complete noob when it comes to electronics but have been searching google and havent found anything and was just wondering if any of you can help guide me a little.
So I have this set of wireless doorbell and receivers, and Ive found mixed things on the internet as to whether or not Im able to pair more buttons to the existing set of receivers, and if there is a limit on how many I can pair.

Does anyone know if I can find this out from looking at the circuit boards, and if im only able to have the button is it possible to change it to be able to pair more than this. Really would love some guidance on where to begin and any help would be really appreciated :)

In the end id like to have a set of 6/7 buttons and 2 receivers, but can't find a set like this online which is why ive turned to stack exchange.

https://www.amazon.co.uk/Wireless-Doorbell-AVANTEK-Waterpoof-Operating/dp/B07KG9VXF6/

Comment: Several buttons probably need also different indication for each button. What about an integrated  2 way phone to be able to ask "who's there and what's up"?

Comment: @user287001 sorry just to clarify, why would they need different indication?

Comment: Having 7 buttons in the same place with same function (=triggering the same single sound) doesn't look especially economical. I guess the buttons either have different signalling meanings or they are in different places. In both cases the listener maybe wants to know which button is pressed.

Comment: @user287001 Yes would be in different places in the house, as would like the dog to be able to let everyone know she needs to be let out for a wee/poop, but at different times stays in different rooms with the doors closed

Comment: Similar devices are widely used. For instance, garage door openers. One received and few transmitters can be paired, but amount of transmitters is depended of model.

Comment: You have 7 entrances??

Comment: Maybe it's so the servants know which room Heba is calling from.

Comment: @Transistor Lol no, got a shared house with a shared dog, but everyones got zoom meetings nowadays so sometimes puppy doesnt get let out

Answer (score 1):

These are common in large distributors like Banggood.  They use a simple shared f so connect as many of the same as you want.

### Anecdotal

I installed one about a year ago and the Rx twin C cells died and the Remote CR2032 is such a low power Tx, that I would only believe Operating at 300 m range, is fictitious best case with wall reflectors pointing in the right direction without obstruction. I got 3m only thru the front door frame.

As it was the Rx could only pick up the Tx near the front door Tx with Rx just inside the front hall and not in the kitchen or den. The speaker was so puny , it was barely audible with some background TV noise.

So I modified it.

Added 0.5 m magnet wire to CR2032 gnd along exterior door frame to act as an antenna. This made it work anywhere inside the bungalow.
A big improvement would be a hidden lithium manganese dioxide cell as large as the Tx and button.

Put Rx inside a large plastic coffee container and added a 5” speaker on top instead of lid using AWG magnet wire. Then hid it behind a cabinet. Now we could hear it inside , but not outside.  Good enough. Replaced C cells with the best Panasonic Alkaline cells. The door bells are hardly used, so it is 10y shelf life I am hoping for.

Comment: If your supplier stopped selling them , I can understand why.